# What emotions do :3 and :S convey?

Tags: meaning, emoticons

Often I find people [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) using emoticons.  Most are simple to decipher, but I can't figure out what these two mean.

> :3

and

> :S

What do they mean?

Comment: I never use smileys, but I always interpret the first one as buttface. So don't listen to me.

Comment: This doesn't relate to English IMO.

Comment: @Mahnax It's not *specific* to English (theoretically), but it's a major factor in a lot of communications using the English language.

Comment: I see no difference between asking about how to use this and asking about how to use some other aspect of English communication properly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As with most smileys, but especially with these unclear ones, how they are being used by any given person might vary. However, this is my experience with them...

:3 is an animal face, especially a cat. It either means "cute" or "mischievous." As in "I'm too cute to be mad at, right?"

:S means "worried". The mouth is all contorted as if in pain. As in, "this topic makes me upset."

Comment: `:S` means "strange".  But even in 2020 AFAICS there is no Unicode equivalent.
`:/` means "worried" and there is the equivalent ''.

Answer (score 8):

:3, as suggested by Jeremy, is a cutesy animal face.

:S, however in my experience, is a confused smile, as you see in MSN messenger.

Comment: :S in my experience is supposed to be like Charlie Brown's face when the mouth is just a squiggly line. It can mean confusion, embarrassment, or being at a loss for words, or some combination of them.